# django admin action

Tags: django, django-admin

Hi I'd like to send password reset emails from within the user admin and have an action set up.

I can't determine if it's possible to use the password_reset view. Can I loop over the queryset using the view to generate the token and send the email?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. **Subclass UserAdmin**, you can import it from `django.contrib.auth.admin`
2. **Add the action you added, use [PasswordResetForm](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.3.X/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L107)** by [reverse engineering the password_reset view](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.3.X/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L132).
3. **Unregister User from admin.site**, `admin.site.register(User)`
4. **Register your subclass** as the modeladmin for User

Here's an example (thanks Chris Pratt for pushing the use of unregister/register):

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import default_token_generator
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class YourUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    actions = list(UserAdmin.actions) + ['send_reset_password']

    def send_reset_password(modeladmin, request, queryset):
        for user in queryset:
            form = PasswordResetForm({'email': user.email})
            form.full_clean()
            form.save({
                'use_https': request.is_secure(),
                'token_generator': default_token_generator,
                'from_email': settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
                'email_template_name': 'registration/password_reset_email.html',
                'request': request
            })

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, YourUserAdmin)
```

Comment: There's no need to monkey patch `UserAdmin`. Just subclass it and override any attributes or methods as necessary. Then, you just `admin.site.unregister(UserAdmin)` and `admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)`.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the difference, probably it's slightly cleaner without monkey patch. Thanks !

Comment: I'd doing the unregister thing...
@jpic This leaves me with: 
'PasswordResetForm' object has no attribute 'users_cache'

Comment: Anytime you monkey patch, you open yourself up to odd behaviors or errors if the code behind the scenes changes. Subclassing and overriding is much safer.

Comment: Thanks jpic. I get bad header errors with this code. I removed the kwargs from the form.save() and it works a treat.